# Return the unmatched rows from the regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, series

If I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
      Sequence     Rating
 0    HYHIVQKF     1
 1    YGEIFEKF     2
 2    TYGGSWKF     3
 3    YLESFYKF     4
 4    YYNTAVKL     5
 5    WPDVIHSF     6
```

This is the code that I am using the return the rows that match the following pattern: 
`\b.[YF]\w+[LFI]\b`

```
pat = r'\b.[YF]\w+[LFI]\b'
new_df.Sequence.str.contains(pat)

new_df[new_df.Sequence.str.contains(pat)]
```

The above code is returning the rows that match the pattern, but what can I use to return the unmatched rows?

Expected Output:

```
     Sequence  Rating
1    YGEIFEKF   2
3    YLESFYKF   4
5    WPDVIHSF   6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do a negation of your existing Boolean series:

```
df[~df.Sequence.str.contains(pat)]
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
   Sequence  Rating
1  YGEIFEKF       2
3  YLESFYKF       4
5  WPDVIHSF       6
```

Brief explanation:

```
df.Sequence.str.contains(pat)
```

will return a Boolean series:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Sequence, dtype: bool
```

Negating it using `~` yields

```
~df.Sequence.str.contains(pat)

0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: Sequence, dtype: bool
```

which is another Boolean series you can pass to your original dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `~` for [not](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
pat = r'\b.[YF]\w+[LFI]\b'
new_df[~new_df.Sequence.str.contains(pat)]

#   Sequence    Rating
#1  YGEIFEKF    2
#3  YLESFYKF    4
#5  WPDVIHSF    6
```

Answer (score 2):

[Psidom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45557132/21945) is more elegant, but another way to solve this problem is to modify the regex pattern to use a negative lookahead assertion, and then use `match()` instead of `contains()`:

```
pat = r'\b.[YF]\w+[LFI]\b'
not_pat = r'(?!{})'.format(pat)

>>> new_df[new_df.Sequence.str.match(pat)]
   Sequence  Rating
0  HYHIVQKF       1
2  TYGGSWKF       3
4  YYNTAVKL       5

>>> new_df[new_df.Sequence.str.match(not_pat)]
   Sequence  Rating
1  YGEIFEKF       2
3  YLESFYKF       4
5  WPDVIHSF       6
```