# Getting unmatched Pandas rows based on regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a CSV file which contains 10 columns (c1 to c10) and it mainly has numeric data. I want to extract all those rows where any of the cell value does not match the decimal number pattern of "#####.###" (5 digits before the decimal point and 3 digits after.) So the regex which I have formed is  r'^\d{5}[.]\d{3}$'

I have used ^ and $ because anything unmatched with the given format should be returned.

If the single cell does not have above pattern, then entire row should be returned. Here is what I have tried:

```
Sample input can be (no. of columns does not really matter)-
c1          c2           c3
12345.455  14567.83333  14562.125
14789.123  14725.456    1234567.124589
21445.658  45678.899    45678.369
```

First 2 rows should be returned and last row is in correct format.

```
### What I have tried till now -

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv") ## converting csv to dataframe
pattern = r'^\d{5}[.]\d{3}$' 
df = df.astype(str)  ## getting dataframe as string



### I am using ~ to negate as I need unmatched rows.

df1 = df[~df['c1'].str.contains(pattern)]
df2 = df[~df['c2'].str.contains(pattern)]
df3 = df[~df['c3'].str.contains(pattern)]
df4 = df[~df['c4'].str.contains(pattern)]
df5 = df[~df['c5'].str.contains(pattern)]
df6 = df[~df['c6'].str.contains(pattern)]
df7 = df[~df['c7'].str.contains(pattern)]
df8 = df[~df['c8'].str.contains(pattern)]
df9 = df[~df['c9'].str.contains(pattern)]
df10 = df[~df['c10'].str.contains(pattern)]

final_df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10])
print(final_df)
```

But this code returns some extra rows which are not supposed to be there.
Any help..? A Similar question is [Return the unmatched rows from the regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45557050/return-the-unmatched-rows-from-the-regex-pattern).

Comment: Do you have an example of a row that is not supposed to be there? Or maybe a 10-line slice of table.csv? Your regex looks right, but maybe the ~ is not quite doing what you think.

Comment: Hi @aschultz I have edited the question. can you plz have a look.?

Comment: Hmm. Could you try a row with 3 entries like 123456.7890? Then run the program. Then change one of the entries to 12345.678. My guess is that your program is looking for rows where *one* of the entries is #####.###, instead of *all*, so the first row will be ignored, but the second won't.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to return rows that do not match with `XXXXX.YYY` pattern where `X` and `Y` are digits.

Edit based on OPs update:

```
c1          c2           c3
12345.455  14567.83333  14562.125
14789.123  14725.456    1234567.124589
21445.658  45678.899    45678.369
```

Regex is:

```
pattern = r'^(\d{5})(.)(\d{3})$'
```

Also for better efficiency of not writing 10 lines or more for the number of columns, I would do:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for column in df:
    newdf = df[~df[column].str.contains(pattern)]
    final_df = final_df.append(newdf)

print(final_df)
```

This gives me:

```
          c1           c2              c3
0  12345.455  14567.83333       14562.125
1  14789.123    14725.456  1234567.124589
```

If you have any duplicates, do this to remove them:

```
final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates(final_df.columns, keep = 'first')
```

Comment: Hi @Ankur Sinha,  in your answer shouldn't it return second row as well ? sdas da s 12345.678 asd a  sdas da s 12345.678 asd a - this should return as unmatched row..

Comment: Updated based on your edit and I get the output you are expecting but even your code seems fine to me. Also could you please tell, What do you mean by you are getting more rows, because if let's say, in the first row and second row in col2 is an unmatch, and first row in col1 is an unmatch, you will end up getting three rows from the unmatch group (1 being extra duplicate). Is this your problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate giving us the extra rows that you are getting which you are not supposed to?

Comment: Hi @Ankur, Yes.. you are right. duplicate rows are getting added because we iterating over columns. But even when I tried your code.. it does not remove duplicate rows. Can you please have a look at it once..? Thanks for taking out the time.!

Comment: Yes, thought so. I added the code to remove the duplicates, have a look :) Now it should be fine.